# Django CMS 3.1 and Django 1.7.8 custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm using Django 1.7.8 with DjangoCMS 3.1. I want to add my custom user model. I get exception that my custom model is not registered. I found similar issues but I can't fix it.

**My project structure:**

```
.
├── djangocms
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── feature.html
│   │   ├── menu.html
│   │   └── page.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
├── media
├── project.db
├── static
└── users
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── apps.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

In settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'
```

users/models.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField('email address', max_length=255,
                          unique=True, db_index=True)
```

**update**

I found that some apps crash custom user model in DjangoCMS, when I add comments then django registry finds my model. My settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    #'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',

    #'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    #'djangocms_style',
    #'djangocms_column',
    #'djangocms_file',
    #'djangocms_flash',
    #'djangocms_googlemap',
    #'djangocms_inherit',
    #'djangocms_link',
    #'djangocms_picture',
    #'djangocms_teaser',
    #'djangocms_video',
    'reversion',

    'djangocms',
    'users',
)
```

Comment: did you add 'users' to the INSTALLED_APPS setting?

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide  yes I did.

Comment: @user3455448 can you share your repository? or at least share the entire `settings.py`

Comment: @user3455448 before that please verify that removing the `pyc` and restarting the server still doesn't help.

Comment: @Yeo removing pyc sitll doesn't help. I share my repo https://github.com/codecats/djangocms-custom-user

Comment: @user3455448 Hey Yoooo `UserProfile` is abstract !!!! You can't do that. That's why it is not registered as Model

Comment: So you update your question... You asking anything there or just to say something awesome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cannot set [abstract model](https://github.com/codecats/djangocms-custom-user/blob/dcf764774e506006f4d876b4459fb470c22afb91/users/models.py#L9) into your `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.
Basically Abstract Model is not yet a concrete model. You need a concrete [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) model instead. That's also explain why your `Model 'users.UserProfile' is not registered`

And also, something is strange with your `UserProfile`, It is suppose to be called `User` or `MyUser` or `WhateverUser` instead. Django has a historical reason that `UserProfile` naming convention is always refer to an additional information of the `User` model via `OneToOneField`. [See this Django 1.4 (old docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

[See this to you can create a custom user model.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser)

Comment: great, So you update your question... are You asking anything there or just to say something interesting?

Answer (score 2):

The application in which the model is defined **must be loaded before cms in INSTALLED_APPS.** You'll need to move `'users'` up the list, before the CMS stuff.

Additionally, DjangoCMS expects a user model with at minimum the following fields:

- email
- password
- is_active
- is_staff
- is_superuser

Additionally, it should inherit from AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin (or AbstractUser), and must define one field as the USERNAME_FIELD (see Django documentation for more details) and define a get_fullname() method.

The models must also be editable via django admin and have an admin class registered.